# Is there a way to update Key to include ancestor

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have update my entities to include ancestor in Google App Engine but also I need to migrate existing data to have that ancestor.

Is there a way to update [Key](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Key) to include ancestor? Creating new Key with same ID and Kind and ancestor includes creates new record in datastore instead of updating existing one.

I am aware that I could resave those entities in new format and delete old ones, but is there any other way?

Comment: No. I would leave the answer at that but SO won't let me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, keys are immutable, so you can not update the key of an existing entity. You need to create new entity, copy key/properties, save it and delete the old one.